# Magento custom block not showing on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, xml, custom-block

I'm trying to create custom block to show some info on the page, but got some weird issue that this block not showing. Already broke my brain by trying to debug why. 
There are some code snippets:
**config.xml**

```
<config>
<module>
    <Module_Design>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
    </Module_Design>
</module>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <module_design>
            <class>Module_Design_Helper</class>
        </module_design>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <module_design>
            <class>Module_Design_Model</class>
        </module_design>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <module_design>
            <class>Module_Design_Block</class>
        </module_design>
    </blocks>
</global>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <module_design>
                <file>module/design.xml</file>
            </module_design>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<default>
    <module_design>
        <notification>
            <!-- Promotion bar -->
            <stickybanner_enabled>0</stickybanner_enabled>
            <stickybanner_position>top</stickybanner_position>
            <stickybanner_visibility>default</stickybanner_visibility>
            <stickybanner_sort_order>1</stickybanner_sort_order>

            <!-- Cookie Opt-In -->
            <cookie_optin_enabled>1</cookie_optin_enabled>
            <cookie_optin_position>top</cookie_optin_position>
            <cookie_optin_visibility>default</cookie_optin_visibility>
            <cookie_optin_lifetime>604800</cookie_optin_lifetime>
            <cookie_optin_sort_order>0</cookie_optin_sort_order>
        </notification>
    </module_design>
</default>
```

**design.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="design.notifications">
                <block type="module_design/notification_stickybanner" name="module_design_notification_stickybanner"
                       as="stickybanner" template="module/design/notification/stickybanner.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**Stickybanner.php**

```
class Module_Design_Block_Notification_Stickybanner extends Module_Design_Block_Notification_Abstract
{
    ...

    /**
     * check, if the notification should be shown
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isShown()
    {
        if (!parent::isEnabled()) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($this->isTypeDefault()) {
            return true;
        }
        if (Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get($this->_cookieName)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    ...
```

template **stickybanner.phtml**

```
<?php
/* @var $this Module_Design_Block_Notification_Stickybanner */
if (!$this->isShown()) {
    return;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your block type in backoffice **System > Permissions > Blocks** ?

[image: Screenshot]

**update**

There is a typo error in your **config.xml** file

```
<config>
    <module>
        <Module_Design>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </Module_Design>
    </module>
```

Should be...

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Module_Design>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </Module_Design>
    </modules>
```

Comment: `<system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <module_design>
                                        <title>Module Design</title>
                                    </module_design>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>`

Comment: in adminhtm.xml you mean?

Comment: I mean the backoffice section

Comment: yes, I did it. Also I see all fields for it in backend and in database.

Comment: 99% sure problem in layout. Even if I do simple die/alert it's still not shows on page

Comment: mmm change parent block definition & try core/template

Comment: nope, same story

Comment: No exceptions in Magento log files?

Comment: well, something find "Invalid block type: Mage_Design_Block_Notification_Stickybanner"

Comment: Paste full config.xml to check then

Comment: done, please have a look

Comment: I see a typo there, change "module" by "modules" in the beginning

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: yes i changed. Thx but it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

**design.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="design/notification_stickybanner" name="module_design_notification_stickybanner" template="module/design/notification/stickybanner.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**config.xml**

```
<blocks>
    <design>
        <class>Module_Design_Block</class>
    <design>
</blocks>
```

`after_body_start` is already a structural block so your `module_design_notification_stickybanner` will be rendered automatically.

The `stickybanner.phtml` should be in : `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/module/design/notification/stickybanner.phtml`

The `design.xml` should be in : `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/module/design.xml`

### Update:

**config.xml**

```
<modules>
    <Module_Design>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
    </Module_Design>
</modules>
```

instead of

```
<module>
    <Module_Design>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
    </Module_Design>
</module>
```

Don't forget the module declaration:

`app/etc/modules/Module_Design.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Module_Design>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Module_Design>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: tried your solution as well. Still not working

Comment: look my update, did your module works ? if it doesn't work, please share your full module code with full path files

Comment: my bet is the module is not being correctly loaded, agree